# What is contours in computer vision?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am currently studying a computer vision module in college.
 I would like to get a theoretical understanding of what contours are in computer vision and what they are used for.

Comment: More information about contours in OpenCV : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html#table-of-content-contours

Answer (score 8):

A contour is simply the boundary of an object in an image.  Various representations of contours (e.g. chain code, Fourier descriptors, shape context) are used to recognize or categorize objects.

This assumes that you have a way to segment out an object and find its boundary, which itself is not a trivial problem. One particular class of algorithms for finding boundaries is called *active contours* or *snakes*. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Thank you Dima for your answer.It answered my original question.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) you can go through the official documentation of **opencv**, where they say that contour is a simple curve which joins continuous points with same color or intensity.

I used the concept of contours in [hand gesture recognition](https://github.com/SaiVinay007/hand-gesture-recognition) where i have used the area bounded by contours as a basis to remove the noise and detect only the hand part in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Contour is a boundary around something that has well defined edges, which means that the machine is able to calculate difference in gradient (significant difference in magnitude of pixel value), try to see if the same difference continues and forms a recognisable shape and draw a boundary around it. Opencv can do it for a lot of shapes and they are shown in the link below.

Just imagine how you do it with your eyes. You're in a room and you create a boundary in your mind when you see a frame or a monitor or a ball. Exactly the same way contours work in opencv. As @Dima said, various algorithms are used for this purpose.

If you need examples and how contours are represented in opencv, here's a [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open CV python provides us with contours and several edge detection features to identify several attributes of objects. Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points(along the boundary), having same colour or intensity.

### Use of binary image in contour detection:

Contours are useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition. We take in binary image (in other words, images whose pixels have only 2 possible values).So before finding contours, apply threshold or canny edge detection.

### Steps for finding the contours:

1)Convert to grayscale

2)Convert to binary image

3)Find contours

### Draw contours :

To draw the contours, cv2.drawContours function is used. It can also be used to draw any shape provided you have its boundary points.

### Properties of contours:

1)To find the area.

2)To find the perimeter